# JSON not being parsed after API call

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to parse JSON that I receive as a response after calling an API using URLSession.

This is my code:

```
            let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            if error != nil {
                callback(.failure(.parsingError))
                return
            }

            print(String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8) as String?)

            if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, (300...1000).contains(httpResponse.statusCode) {
                callback(.failure(.badResponse))
                return
            }

            do {
                if let responseObject = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as? [String: Any] {
                    callback(.success(responseObject))
                    return
                }
            } catch {
                callback(.failure(.jsonParsingError))
            }
        }
```

This is the response that I am getting from the API

```
[
    {
        "id": 7,
        "name": "Demo 1",
        "description": "Description 1",
        "created": "2020-04-10T16:47:27.462570Z",
        "loc": null,
        "list1": [],
        "list2": []
    }
]
```

And this is what I can see from `print(String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8) as String?)`

```
Optional("[{\"id\":7,\"name\":\"Demo 1\",\"description\":\"Description 1\",\"created\":\"2020-04-10T16:47:27.462570Z\",\"loc\":null,\"list1\":[],\"list2\":[]}]")
```

I used debugger and I can see that it never gets inside `if let responseObject = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as? [String: Any] {`

Any advice what can be the problem?

Comment: This is an `array` coming from the API and you are trying to parse this into a `dictionary`
Use `[dictionary<String,Any>]` instead of `[String: Any]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using `Codable` instead of `JSONSerialization`.

With a model struct like

```
struct Item: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let name, description, created: String
    let loc: Int? // replace with appropriate type
    let list1, list2: [Int] // replace with appropriate type
}

typealias Items = [Item]
```

you can parse the response using

```
do {
   let items = try JSONDecoder().decode(Items.self, from: data!)
} catch {
   print(error)
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This is great!

Answer (score 1):

Please read the JSON carefully.

There are only two different collection types, array `[]` and dictionary `{}`. The JSON is clearly an array. You can also return an error on failure

```
if let responseObject = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as? [[String: Any]] {
   callback(.success(responseObject))
} else {
   print("JSON is not an array")
   callback(.failure(.jsonParsingError))
}
```

And you might adjust your `Result` type, too